# Обьясните в чем разница между symbol и string

Tags: ruby

На примере 2-х хешей
`hash={:fruit=>"Apple", :vegetable="Cucumber"}`  и   `hash={"fruit"=>"Apple", "vegetable"="Cucumber"}`.
Расскажите в чем разница между этими сущностями и где применяют symbol.

Comment: [When to use symbols instead of strings in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621073/when-to-use-symbols-instead-of-strings-in-ruby)

Comment: [What's the difference between a string and a symbol in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255078/whats-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-symbol-in-ruby)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Переменная - это именованная область памяти, она содержит имя и значение, значение можно менять.

Строка - это просто область памяти, которую вы можете изменять.

Символ - это просто имя. Эта конструкция очень популярна в функциональных языках и обычно называется атомом - нечто неделимое и неизменное. Например, белый цвет, :white - нет надобности для значения, нет надобности для изменения - белый цвет останется белым цветом, чтобы не происходило. Это символ в Ruby.

Используется символы там, где значение не требуется, например, для перечислений, передачи имени ключа или метода. Строки и символы можно преобразовывать друг в друга, однако это разные классы.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что стоит осветить вопрос с **технической** точки зрения (отвечу на вопрос *как?*, но не на вопрос *зачем?*). Прежде всего общий факт: любое значение в Ruby — объект. И объект уникально идентифицируется ссылкой на него. Можно получить производное от ссылки значение из `объект.object_id`.

(где не указано явно, примеры на Ruby 2.2.3)

- Со **строкой** всё более-менее понятно: это просто ссылка на буфер конечной (но меняемой при необходимости) длины, в котором хранятся символы.

  - Содержимое этого буфера можно менять по своему усмотрению (т. е. строки **мутабельны**), а потому сохраняя ссылку на строку в одном месте, нельзя быть уверенным, что при очередном взгляде по ссылке там будет то же, что было ранее.
  - Одинаковые строки **обычно*** являются разными объектами:

    ```
    ''.object_id == ''.object_id # => false
    ```
- **Символы** это небольшая *обёртка над строками*, объекты которой *принципиально иначе хранятся в памяти*.

  - Способ хранения такой, что символ с определённым названием (строкой), будучи употреблённым в пределах одного процесса Ruby в любом месте будет **одним и тем же объектом**. Это позволяет очень быстро сравнивать символы *на равенство*: достаточно сравнить ссылки на них, даже не смотря в его строку, т. е. выяснить, не один и тот же ли это объект. Это `O(1)`, тогда как сравнение строк на равенство `O(object.length)`.
  - Этот способ хранения называется **интернирование**, все строки-названия символов в Ruby интернированы. В Ruby `String#intern` и `String#to_sym` синонимы. `.to_sym`, на мой взгляд, предпочтительнее, т. к. отражает настоящий тип возвращаемого значения.
  - Принцип действия неплохо описан в документации к [`String intern()` в Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29): класс где-то внутри себя поддерживает глобальный набор всех интернированных значений. Когда запрашивается получение интернированного значения, берётся либо равное ему значение из набора, либо запрашиваемое значение копируется (!) в набор и возвращается оно же.
  - Когда-то все символы, появившись однажды, никогда не исчезали, сборщик мусора их не трогал даже если ими переставали пользоваться. Поэтому делать символы из строк, прилетающих от пользователя, было опасно: присылая различные строки тоннами, можно было занять символами из них кучу оперативной памяти, вызвав её нехватку и падение процесса. **Ба-бах.** Это исправили в Ruby 2.2.

---

*тем временем на горизонте...*

*** ...но это со временем может измениться.** В Ruby 2.3 появилась **опция** "заморозки" всех литералов строк в коде. В Ruby 3.0 она и вовсе будет включена по умолчанию.

Заморозка объекта делает невозможной его изменение (мутацию, т. е. объект становится иммутабельным). Объект можно заморозить методом `freeze`. И применительно к строкам интерпретатор может применить интересную оптимизацию: одинаковые литералы представлять одним и тем же объектом.

```
''.object_id == ''.object_id # => true # хоть вроде сравнение такое же!
```

Это логично: единственная опасность мутабельного объекта в том, что его содержимое может быть внезапно изменено где-то очень далеко. По-хорошему, где это критично, объект нужно заморозить. **Это можно сделать явно и в версиях постарше** или при выключенной опции автозаморозки, и эффект воспроизведётся:

```
''.freeze.object_id == ''.freeze.object_id # => true
```

Но **заморозка и интернирование разные вещи**, в отличие от символов не всегда одинаковые замороженные строки это один и тот же объект:

```
a = ''
a.freeze # он деструктивный, замораживает тот объект, на котором вызван
b = ''.freeze
a.object_id == b.object_id # => false
```

Answer (score 1):

Как верно сказал @cheops, Строка -- это область памяти, которую можно править и пр. Символы же можно воспринимать как константы, значения которых явным образом не указываются, а служат для избежания магических чисел. Наподобие [enum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type).